# Why do we use the definite article in the expression "quite the [noun]"?

Tags: expressions, articles, definite-articles

Like: "*quite the singer*", "*quite the writer*", etc. while he/she is just a singer/writer and is not the only singer/writer, etc in that context.

Comment: http://www.theonion.com/articles/annoying-coworker-precedes-all-nouns-with-quite-th,3712/

Comment: I think all of the answers so far either don't attempt to answer the specific question "why do we use the definite article", or else give an answer that is wrong. Unfortunately, I believe this is because there isn't an answer: it is an idiom, and not analysable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Quite a* (and *quite the*, sometimes used ironically) indicates that the specified thing or thing is recognized as notable, remarkable, or impressive.

> Quite a party, isn't it?
>   It has been quite a year.
>   Quite the little horsewoman, aren't you?

*Quite the thing* is a dated way to say *socially accepted*.

> She was quite the thing in heels and stockings and lipstick.

<sub>[The examples are taken from the NOAD]</sub>

Comment: +1 for noting that "quite the" (as opposed to "quite a") is generally ironical, or condescending.

Answer (score 3):

Stating "Quite *a* [noun]" indicates that one is notable, while stating "quite *the* [noun]" is remarkable.

It is mostly the difference between the indeterminate (*a*—or, just another [noun]) and the determinate (*the*—a specific [noun]).

Answer (score 2):

We use the definite article to show uniqueness.

This case, saying "quite the singer" suggests that the singer is unique in some way -- e.g. being noticeably more talented than the others.

Comment: Doesn't "quite a singer" also mean that the singer is noticeably more talented than others?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes. But I would say that's omitting an adjective such as "good".

Comment: I disagree with this answer. I don't think it shows uniqueness at all: it is about this person being an outstanding singer, there is no comparison made or implied with other singers. Consider the (slightly old-fashioned) "He's looking quite the gentleman!"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @awm as in cases where one says **quite the [noun]**, he wishes to indicate a specific trait of the **[noun]** that even among **its** commonalities makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @ColinFine, "quite the X" is simply an idiom. It's not any sort of standard grammatical construction and so cannot be explained according to standard grammatical rules. Other idioms that include inexplicable instances of "the" include "what the hell,"  "the hell you say," and to be "for the asking."

Answer (score 0):

If 'life is context', then think about why this phrase has become so over-used during the past 2-3 years. To me, the increased use of 'quite the' rather than 'quite a' is to use the phrase to appear smarter or more 'hip'. In America, we are continually hearing commercials with phrases meant to imply that a 'hip' or 'in the know' person talks a certain way. And the commercial message is to get the listener to do what is wanted by the vendor.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Can you provide any references or examples that demonstrate this phenomenon, or is this merely personal speculation? I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for an introduction to our guidelines and standards, which differ from those of most traditional discussion forums.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a recent phenomenon, not the recent phenomenon so to speak. But, actually, I associate "quite the..." with US English, which is now being used here (New Zealand). Interesting to read that "quite a..." was/is used in the USA.